# Unselecting route because it is no longer selectable chromecast Android Sender

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

Chromecast is causing this error only sometimes when trying to connect to a device on my network, but i am not sure why when the same build works on other devices.

Can someone please help me?

`"unselecting the current device "07-18 15:22:20.592: I/MediaRouter(3628): Unselecting the current route because 
it is no longer selectable: MediaRouter.RouteInfo{ uniqueId=com.google.android.gms/.cast.media.CastMediaRouteProviderService:35b39330e73d45f54bf12f20a90529a2, name=old reliable, description=Chromecast, enabled=true, connecting=false, playbackType=1, playbackStream=-1, volumeHandling=0, volume=0, volumeMax=20, presentationDisplayId=-1, extras=Bundle[{com.google.android.gms.cast.EXTRA_CAST_DEVICE="old reliable" (35b39330e73d45f54bf12f20a90529a2)}], providerPackageName=com.google.android.gms }`

Answer (score 0):

This might be related to a discovery issue that will be addressed in the next Play Services update, this ticket tracks that: https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/detail?id=314