# Restoring chromecast connection fails: Unselecting the current route because it is no longer selectable

Tags: android, chromecast

I'm developing an Android app that supports Chromecast.

When trying to reconnect, in the callback:

`public void onRouteAdded(final MediaRouter router, final MediaRouter.RouteInfo route)`

I check whether the routeId is the one I was connected and in that case I select it calling:

```
mRouter.selectRoute(newRoute)
```

What happens is that my `onRouteSelected` callback is triggered but just after that the `onRouteUnselected` is called. This does not happen on all the phones.

Tracing what happens I saw that the implementation of `selectRoute` ends sending a "route unselected" message to an `Handler`. The passed route is the default one so the one that was selected when I tried to select the new one. The route that I receive in the `onRouteUnselected` is the new one instead so the one that was just selected.

Has anyone seen this issue?

**Edited**
In the logs I see "Unselecting the current route because it is no longer selectable"

Following the solution suggested in [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24832907/unselecting-route-because-it-is-no-longer-selectable-chromecast-android-sender) I installed the new version of the Google Play Services. I'm still using the jdk 1.6. The problem now is that I get onConnectionFailed with `ConnectionResult.SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED`. 
To fix this issue with the version I had to force gradle to use version 5.0.89 that is the one that is installed on the phone. After having done this the application runs again on the phone but the reconnection still fails

**Edited2**
Please notice that you need to have a strong reference (mRouter) to a router object in your "ChromecastManager" class and you should use that one to select the route. You should also look in `mRouter.getRoutes()` for the route with `newRoute.getId() == oldRoute.getId()`. So you can't call `mRouter.selectRoute(route)` where route is the object passed to `onRouteAdded`

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediarouteprovider.html  hmmm Id review the link and continue looking very closely at the protocol flow where u are removing an explicity UI dialog and button control with find/connect to discoverd route.

Comment: Sorry I did not understan why that would be relevant. I'm not extending a Media Route Provider. And why would the UI level be involved here? When reconnecting everything is done in the background

Comment: then what? You use CCL?

Comment: Oh.. im more in (android + CCL ) camp . i guess u are using 'mediaRouter' for stuff i would get from CCL. Im not much help on this.

Comment: Thank you anyway. Following the suggestion in https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/detail?id=314. I updated the Play service lib. Now I'm having problem because it asks me to update the compiler to 1.7. I did it but I still see an error because CastDevice is not define

Comment: ive been avoid 1.7 like the plague.

Comment: i think i use PlayServices bundled w/ SDK/ ADT 22.6 in Eclipse and it is still 1.6.

Comment: I get "warning: com/google/android/gms/common/api/PendingResult.class(com/google/android/gms/common/api:PendingResult.class): major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported by this compiler.
It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.". And many other warnings like this.

Comment: what is the version of the play store services on the phone that exhibits that issue?

Comment: Google Play Service ver 5.0.89 (1307510-038)

Comment: the major vrsn error  you get can be resolve by getting version of SDK that wraps a version of services built on 1.6.

 dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r22.6.2-linux.tgz 

for that backvrsn of SDK/play-services .
i build on 1.6 and run on phone with 4.4 and with 5.0.89 and Chromecast work great. bottom line - not forced into 1.7 from 1.6 just yet.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it is working now. The only thing I did was to execute the router.selectRoute asynchronously and not in the onRouteAdded. So I execute the selection in an Handler.

So to update the Google Service isn't necessary. In case you update the Google Service as I did you do not need to use JDK 1.7. I don't know why I get the warning

> "warning: com/google/android/gms/common/api/PendingResult.class(com/google/android/gms/com‌​mon/api:PendingResult.class): major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported by this compiler. It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded."

even if `openjdk-6-jdk` is already the newest version.